# Creating responsive container with particular element aligned at the center

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There are 3 ul container, ul.spread-price is sandwiched between ul.table-sell and ul.table-buy container, These three container are wrapped inside other containers(eg : div.order-view-container). At particular instance of time, the ul.spread-price container should be in the middle with the ul.table-sell and ul.table-buy container above and below having the scrolling effect respectively.

### **Case 1:**

when i scroll on ul.table-sell the ul.spread-container reached to the top of the div.order-view-container touching it and having ul.table-sell content scrolling effect at the bottom of ul.spred-price.
**

### Case 2:

** when i scroll on ul.table-buy the ul.spread-container reached to the bottom of the div.order-view-container touching it and having ul.table-buy content scrolling effect at the top of ul.spred-price.

At present i have achieved this in the large screen 1920 x 1080. But the same is not working for all the devices.enter image description here

[image: 2.12 INR SPREAD element is middle at the page load and also when i clicked]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Function to check when window is resized
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $("ul.spread-price").css('width', $('.order-view-scrollable').width());
        });

        var scrollDivHeight = $('.order-view-scrollable .scrollingdiv').height();
        console.log("scrollDivHeight :"+scrollDivHeight);
        var scrollDivWidth = $('.order-view-scrollable').width();
        var setTopHeight = scrollDivHeight/2;

        $("ul.spread-price").css('width', $('.order-view-scrollable').width());
        $('.order-view-scrollable .scrollingdiv').scrollTop(setTopHeight);

        $(".spread-price").click(function(){
            var scrollDivHeight = $('.order-view-scrollable .scrollingdiv').height();
            var scrollDivWidth = $('.order-view-scrollable').width();
            var setTopHeight = scrollDivHeight/2;
            alert("scrollDivHeight :"+scrollDivHeight+"<br>setTopHeight :"+setTopHeight);
            $('.order-view-scrollable .scrollingdiv').scrollTop(setTopHeight);

        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you please post your `HTML` and `CSS` and create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @IvanModric Ok i will do that

Comment: still waiting for the fiddle ;)

Comment: @IvanModric Sorry to say this but actually there is a lot of html,css styling applied to this. Which are internally co-related to each other. Can you please give me an idea.How this can be achieved. I hope you are clear with my question. If you need   plz let me know.

Comment: @IvanModric I have solved my problem. Anyway thankyou for your concern.